# remove characters before and after character in java

Tags: java, string

I need to delete all characters before and after a specific character using java programming
for example:

**input:** `ab*cd` **output:**`ad`

**input:** `ab**cd` **output:**`ad`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Starstring {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1;
        String res="";
        int n,i=0;

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        str1=sc.next();
        res=str1;
        StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer(str1);
        n=str1.length()-1;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(str1.charAt(i)=='*')
            {
                res=a.delete(i-1, i+2).toString();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The final string is"+res);
    }

}
```

I am getting expected output for `case 1` but `case 2` wrong output with ac as output.I don't know where I am going wrong.Someone please help me.Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Why not do a regex replace? i.e. replace the pattern `.\*+.` with empty string?

Comment: I am new to java and string so tell me in detail.Do we have function called regex replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex to replace more than one `*` with single `*`. Your code will be like below:

```
input:ab*cd output:ad
input ab**cd  ouput:ad
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Starstring {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1;
        String res="";
        int n,i=0;

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        str1=sc.next();
        res=str1;
        str1 = str1.replaceAll("[*]+", "*");// add this line
        StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer(str1);
        n=str1.length()-1;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(str1.charAt(i)=='*')
            {
                res=a.delete(i-1, i+2).toString();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The final string is"+res);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to replace character group in your string. To remove `*` and 1 character before & after it:

```
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(".\\*+."); 
Matcher match = pt.matcher(input);
String output = match.replaceAll("");
//System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
    String str1;
    int n;

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    str1=sc.next();

    sc.close();

    StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer(str1);
    n=a.length();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(str1.charAt(i)=='*')
        {
            int aa = i-1;
            int bb = i+1;
            for(;bb<n; bb++){
                if(str1.charAt(bb)!='*'){
                    break;
                }
            }
            a.delete( aa, bb+1 );
            i = bb;

        }
    }
    String res = a.toString();
    System.out.println("The final string is"+res);
```

But a better java ***regex*** way is :

After reading value from scanner -

```
    String res2 = str1.replaceAll( ".[\\*]+.", "" );
    System.out.println("The final string is"+res2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Vasan regex.. below is the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1;
        String res="";
        int n;

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        str1=sc.next();
        res=str1;
        StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer(str1);
        n=str1.length()-1;

        String[] splitVal = str1.split(".\\*+.");
        String newString ="";
        for(int i=0; i<splitVal.length; i++){
            newString = newString + splitVal[i];
        }

        System.out.println("The final string is "+newString);
    }
```

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str1 = sc.nextLine();
    String[] separated = str1.split(".\\*+.");
    String result = "";
    for(String str : separated) {
        result += str;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what if input is : *abc* or ab*c*de

Comment: *abc* test case can be ignored